# Ruby on rails errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

so am new into all of this. last night I spent 5 hours reading and trying to fix the issues I have. I tried re-installing ruby on rails several times but every time I would try and launch the server I would get errors, other people had similar ones, however mines couldn't be fixed the same way as theirs.
 when I run the command:

```rb
      rails new myapp
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/.git/
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/javascript/channels/consumer.js
      create  app/javascript/channels/index.js
      create  app/javascript/packs/application.js
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/yarn
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/spring.rb
      create  config/storage.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/master.key
      append  .gitignore
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/pids
      create  tmp/pids/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  storage
      create  storage/.keep
      create  tmp/storage
      create  tmp/storage/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb
         run  bundle install
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 13.0.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 1.7.0
Using minitest 5.13.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.6
Using zeitwerk 2.2.2
Using activesupport 6.0.2.1
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.9.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.7
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.5
Using loofah 2.4.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 6.0.2.1
Using rack 2.0.8
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 6.0.2.1
Using nio4r 2.5.2
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.4
Using websocket-driver 0.7.1
Using actioncable 6.0.2.1
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 6.0.2.1
Using activemodel 6.0.2.1
Using activerecord 6.0.2.1
Using mimemagic 0.3.3
Using marcel 0.3.3
Using activestorage 6.0.2.1
Using mini_mime 1.0.2
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailbox 6.0.2.1
Using actionmailer 6.0.2.1
Using actiontext 6.0.2.1
Using public_suffix 4.0.3
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using msgpack 1.3.1
Using bootsnap 1.4.5
Using bundler 1.17.2
Using byebug 11.0.1
Using regexp_parser 1.6.0
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 3.30.0
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using ffi 1.11.3
Using jbuilder 2.9.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using method_source 0.9.2
Using puma 4.3.1
Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
Using thor 1.0.1
Using railties 6.0.2.1
Using sprockets 4.0.0
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Fetching rails 6.0.2.1
Installing rails 6.0.2.1
Using rubyzip 2.0.0
Using sassc 2.2.1
Using tilt 2.0.10
Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
Using sass-rails 6.0.0
Using selenium-webdriver 3.142.7
Using spring 2.1.0
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using sqlite3 1.4.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.2.1
Using web-console 4.0.1
Using webdrivers 4.2.0
Using webpacker 4.2.2
Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 75 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: Spring inserted
* bin/rails: Spring inserted
       rails  webpacker:install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    26: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    25: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    24: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    22: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    20: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    18: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    17: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    16: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    15: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    13: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    11: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     5: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     3: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     1: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    27: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    26: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    25: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    23: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    21: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     2: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
    27: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    26: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    25: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    23: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    21: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
     3: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     1: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    28: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    27: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    26: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    24: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    22: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    20: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    19: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    18: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    17: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    15: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/ccc/Desktop/myapp/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    13: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    11: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:74:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
     5: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
     4: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     2: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/ccc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/msgpack-1.3.1/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
```

this is even a new problem , yesterday the only issue I had was when trying to run the server to see "Yayyou are on rails" but It wouldn't work.

Comment: Very difficult to say. Exactly what steps did you take to install Rails? Were there any warnings or errors during the installation? Did you do any other setup steps before trying to create the app and, if so, what were they? Did you get the errors as a result of running `rails new the_app`? You may need to provide all of the lines of errors since the last couple of lines may not indicate the root cause.

Comment: I followed steps I found online. tried several ones. it involved installing homebrew then ruby then rails then mysql, another one did not include sql. I create another rails app and try launch it on a localhost and paste everything here

Comment: I added the full thing when I try to run: rails new my app

Comment: Your msgpack gem is out of sync with your Ruby version. Try `gem pristine msgpack` to reset and rebuild it. Then try running Rails again.

Comment: @Casper Thank you for the reply, I ran your line of code, it said that it was restored but when I run my rails command again I get the same load error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there could be many things, as you are new and some how got issue. Let us start to diagnose issue by following few commands, see what you get. Run following commands

```
node -v
```

I have response of `12.10.0` you may have close to something, now check npm and yarn versions

```
npm -v
```

My npm is `6.11.3` and you should have something close to it.
Now check yarn version

```
yarn --version
```

My system has `1.17.3` version. Now if everything installed and you got no errors but version are older try to update at close to these version.

First check what version of msgpack is installed

```
gem info msgpack
```

It should be `msgpack (1.3.1)` as per your errors it has also same, also to be safe side check ruby version `ruby -v` it should ruby 2.6.3 version. If you are getting proper information and version of msgpack than it is fine but just do try following

```
gem uninstall msgpack
```

Now go in rails folder and run following command

```
bundle install
```

Now see if you get any error.

Comment: hey @KamalPanhwar node: v12.14
npm: 6.13.4
yarn: 1.21
msgpack : *** local gems ***
ruby: ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin18]
gem uninstall msgpack
Gem 'msgpack' is not installed
bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile


I am trying to UNINSTALL everything and restart over but it seems like I can't manage to delete everything

Comment: ok your commands saying you have not install msgpack, so just go instide your rails folder and than run command `bundle install` make sure you have Gemfile in that folder. Are you using rvm?

Comment: Hey, well I don't know what the error was. but I tried removing it and re installing rails only, and it seems like the web packer is installed properly this time and the localhost is working, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. Uninstall the msgpack and then re-install it or run the following commands

`gem uninstall msgpack`

`bundle install --redownload`